# How to solve printing 1 to 100 properly using loop in c++?

Tags: c++, for-loop

I am a beginner.
As you can see in the below c++ code, I am trying to print 1 to 100 using for loop but always it prints from 72 to 100. I am trying hard but nothing happened.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){

for(int i=1;i\<=100;i++){

    cout<<i<<endl;

}
getch();

}
```

I tried this code also using while loop. I want to print it properly from 1 to 100. I think I am missing something.

Comment: The first part of the output is there, but it's scrolling off the top of the window.

Comment: Code looks fine apart from `\<=` which I assume is just a typo. What happens when you run this code?

Comment: Suggestion, try printing from 1 to 10, then try increasing it a little say 1 to 15, then 1 to 20 and so on. You'll soon understand what is happening

Comment: Is part of your output scrolling off the screen perhaps?

Comment: [After you post, don't run away too fast—leave the question open in your browser for a bit to see if anyone comments.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Wow, two close votes in less than ten minutes? Don't you folks remember what it was like to be a beginner?

Comment: @PeteBecker When I was a beginner I sometimes had to use a teletype. Didn't have this problem then.

Comment: Recommendation: Add what happens, any output, compiler diagnostics, etc...  to the question. Other than the aforementioned typo, what you have looks good and should compile and run on any DOS or Windows PC.

Comment: @DrewDormann the problem is it is showing only just from 72 to 100, not from 1 to 100.

Comment: Ok @john I am trying.

Comment: @Helen it sounds like the console you are using does not have 100 spare lines.  If `\<=` is just a typo in your question, [this code does print 1 to 100](https://godbolt.org/z/G7n3hW3P3).

Comment: Sigh. Voted to reopen. It's quite clear what the problem is, and closing it for "details or clarity" is just mean-spirited.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing you just have to print 1 to 100 using for loop. In your code you just have to remove \ sign from for loop.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out in the comments, it's a scrolling issue with your console or IDE output window. That is, your console window only has 28-30 lines of text.  Are you on a computer where you can resize the output window?  Some online virtual environment where there is no scrollbar?   Does it have a scrollbar for you to go back up the console window history?

[image]

Comment: Thanks @selbie. There is no scrolling issue. I think my console window only has 28-30 lines of text. Like your given picture my console window only shows from 72-100 but blank from 1 to 71. There is no typo issue.

Comment: There appears to be a bug in the terminal/console app on Windows 11 that is similar to what you describe. Is that what you are using?

Comment: Yes, I am using windows 11.

Comment: @Helen - I think this is a known bug you will need to wait for an update on. :(  The workaround appears to be to just print more lines. (e.g. print 1..1000 instead of 1..100)